# Page not foundin on meta , when i click in click on my reputation score

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

click on your reputation score, view reputation privileges

i obtain this page

page not found : https://meta.askubuntu.com/privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't know the details, this feature is relatively new and may not have been rolled out completely.  It should eventually look like other [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) (but use the [meta FAQ](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq) for the reputation required as the numbers change based on each site's needs).

Comment: Also - Your rep is 1 to 1 on both Meta and Parent. To my knowledge there isn't any additional features on meta that *don't* exist on parent. So http://askubuntu.com/privileges page should be the same.

Comment: @Marco: But the rep required for each privilege can vary between meta and parent site.